How to add thresholds with specific ranges to a Highcharts graph?
I’m working on a Highcharts line chart where I need to add thresholds with specific ranges on the x-axis. I want certain areas of the chart to be colored based on these thresholds, Here are the details of my problem:
I’ve used the zone configuration options in Highcharts to try to implement this, but I’m not getting the desired results. Here’s the code I’ve used so far:
Thresholds:
Threshold 1:
    Value: 10°C
    Range: from 100 meters to 500 meters (on the x-axis)

Threshold 2:
    Value: 20°C
    Range: from 600 meters to 2682 meters (on the x-axis)

I want to:
Color the area between 100 meters and 500 meters red if the temperature is above 10°C.
Color the area between 600 meters and 2682 meters red if the temperature is above 20°C.
Display dashed lines at the thresholds of 10°C and 20°C.




  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Thermal Profile'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Temperature 0-10°C',
      data: [
        [0, 20.18], [1, 20.21], [2, 20.38], /* ... */ [99, 19.95] // Data filtered for temperatures below 10°C
      ],
      color: '#83c081', // Color for temperatures < 10°C
      zones: [
        {
          value: 10,
          color: '#83c081'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Temperature 10-20°C',
      data: [
        [100, 10.5], [101, 11.2], /* ... */ [499, 19.8] // Data filtered for temperatures between 10°C and 20°C
      ],
      color: '#dc0059', // Color for temperatures > 10°C and < 20°C
      zones: [
        {
          value: 20,
          color: '#dc0059'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Temperature 20-30°C',
      data: [
        [600, 21.5], [601, 22.0], /* ... */ [2682, 27.5] // Data filtered for temperatures between 20°C and 30°C
      ],
      color: '#83c081', // Color for temperatures > 20°C
      zones: [
        {
          color: '#83c081'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Distance (m)'
    },
    categories: ["0", "550", "1100", "1650", "2150", "2682"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    },
    plotLines: [
      {
        color: '#dc0059',
        dashStyle: 'Dash',  // Dashed line
        value: 10, // Threshold at 10°C
        width: 2,
        label: {
          text: 'Threshold 10°C',
          align: 'right'
        }
      },
      {
        color: '#dc0059',
        dashStyle: 'Dash',  // Dashed line
        value: 20, // Threshold at 20°C
        width: 2,
        label: {
          text: 'Threshold 20°C',
          align: 'right'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x} m</b><br>',
    pointFormat: 'Temperature: {point.y} °C'
  }
});


I think you're very close to the solution. We just need to adjust the zones a bit and maybe add a few more points to better visualize how the zones work. In zones.value, you define the value up to which the points will be colored as specified in zones.color. Higher values will be colored according to the series.color. Please check the demo and let me know if this is the look you wanted to achieve.
API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ey0suh9a/

Thank you for your response. What I want is for the two thresholds not to start at 0, because each has a specific start point and end point. This is a picture of the expected result:

Sorry but I'm not sure i I understand correctly. Now we're defining the zones for specific series and the zone is applied to the whole series. We never define its start point nor the end point. The demo I sent looks very similar to your image, you just need to add more points to make the series connect.


This is a picture of the expected result:
